# Error when trying to convert image sequence to .mov with rvio

Tags: video

I get the following error when using `rvio` or `rvio_hw`. How can I successfully run this command? I need it to find plugin support for the `.mov` format. This error occurs for `.avi` and `.mp4` as well.

```
rvio_hw D:\imagesequence\test.%04d.jpg -o D:\imagesequence\test1.mov
rvio_hw
Version 3.10.4, built on Sep 14 2010 at 19:00:50 (64bit). (L)
Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Tweak Software. All rights reserved.
INFO: D:/imagesequence/test.%04d.jpg
ERROR: TwkMovie: No plugins support (write) format: mov
ERROR: cannot find a way to write D:/imagesequence/test1.mov
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicktimes are not supported on 64bit system 3.10, you should use the 32bit. I think there is a patch for Mac and Linux, you'll get more help on the tweak web page in the forum